# How to get news feed using Facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I want to get my news feed (just as what is shown on facebook home page) using Facebook graph api

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/home

However, the [facebook api document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) says that

```
this is an outdated view, does not reflect the News Feed on facebook.com:
```

Are there any other ways ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[YOUR_ID]/home
```

Note though that you will get almost everything you see on your news feed by **most recent** order and not by **Top Stories** order which is the default view you get when visiting your own news feed.

Also another thing to note is that you wont get promoted stories in the results.

Answer (score 1):

For all wondering if this still works:

> graph.facebook.com/[YOUR_ID]/home

*You need the permission read_stream for this. But you wont get this permission, because its deprecated.*

Unfortunately the endpoint https://graph.facebook.com/[YOUR_ID]/home and the permission are [deprecated and dont work anymore since version 2.4, according to the changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) (search for read_stream).

**Currently there is no alternative for reading the news feed. Only the user's posts can be obtained.**

See this for reference: [Get Home feed requires read_stream which is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309355/get-home-feed-requires-read-stream-which-is-deprecated)