# Get Home feed requires read_stream which is deprecated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the [Home feeds](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/home) of a user using Graph API:

```
/1203306063/home
```

or

```
/me/home
```

but it says `(#200) Requires extended permission: read_stream`

But in fact, when I create access token, I can't specify that permission.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new permission called `user_posts` for that. Information about what you get with that permission is in the changelog for v2.3: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

> This includes the someone's own posts, posts they are tagged in and
>   posts other people make on their Timeline.

Getting access to the whole feed is not possible anymore, `read_stream` is deprecated and there is no direct replacement.

Comment: I'd like to add that you won't receive the user's newsfeed with `user_posts` as with `read_stream`. Instead, this can be use to read the user's timeline.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understand from your comments, read_stream allows to get the newsfeed of an user. However, user_posts only allows to get the user’s timeline.
My only doubt is if we need authentication from the admin of a Facebook page in order to get their timeline or this can be retrieved from API by just requesting it with users_posts (their timeline)

Comment: A look at the docs would solve your question: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#readperms